# When I scale an image (by modifying the matrix in the parent scene(normal Item)), I only get an image with moire in QML

Tags: graphics, qml

[image]
original image↑

[image]
what I get in qml

[image]
what I want to get

I have tried layout's smooth and mipmap but can not achieve the effect, and the difference between nearest and linear does not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, how about sampling the image at different resolutions?

Below I am fitting your image into a 400x200 box, but, I resampling the image by setting `sourceSize` so that it gets resampled at different resolutions.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        width: 420
        height: parent.height
        model: ListModel {
           ListElement { w:200; h:100 }
           ListElement { w:400; h:200 }
           ListElement { w:600; h:300 }
           ListElement { w:800; h:400 }
        }
        delegate: ColumnLayout {
            Label { text: w + " x " + h }
            Image {
                source: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/98dd74d1f18e4dfba334ecea0b371307/data"
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                Layout.preferredWidth: 400
                Layout.preferredHeight: 200
                sourceSize: Qt.size(w, h )
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I researched and found that it would be very inefficient to change the sourceSize dynamically, and I am not using Image, but Item drawn with QSGNode or QQuickFramebufferObject. Is there any method that can be used on Item?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing but it is hard to create your own implementation of image rendering from the ground up. It is not impossible however, comparatively speaking it will be hard to build something comparable to what the Image QML Type does out of the box.